# how to integrate langchain conversations with react chatbot

Tags: python, reactjs, memory, fastapi, langchain

I have a chatbot UI built with react that invokes a Python script and displays the script response using fast API. I use gpt 3.5 to format the question into a query in my Python script. I then send the query to an internal API and return the API response to the chatbot. I now want to add conversation to the chatbot. How do I handle this on the react and python/LLM end?

I tried using Langchain's conversation buffer window. I am expecting similar results with the chatbot. I would like to answer any follow-up questions about the last 5 questions asked on the chatbot. How do I store the question and response and add it to the context next time the Python script is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of `ConversationChain` and `ConversationBufferWindowMemory` functions that achieves your expectation. Where if `k` is set to 5, the model will remember the last 5 interactions

```py
from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
conversation = ConversationChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=PROMPT,
    # memory=ConversationBufferMemory(),
    memory=ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=5),
    verbose=True)
```

Comment: does the llm remember the previous questions if I invoke the script for every question?

Comment: `ConversationChain` with `ConversationBufferWindowMemory` will keep the _conversation_ in memory. As the example, `k=5` means the last 5 interactions will be remembered.